# I cannot execute sql statment dynamically which has into clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am executing this sql statement dynamically in oracle using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement. But when I Do this I get an error 'missing keyword'. I have declare the RULECOUNT variable as NUMBER. When I remove the INTO statement, the sql statement appears to get executed properly.

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT RULE_ID) INTO RULECOUNT FROM(
                        SELECT      
                            distinct a.RULE_ID, Rule_Name, Applicability,
                            Rule_Type, KPI_NAME, BT, DT, Authorised_User,
                            Rule_Date_of_Creation 
                        from vw_rule_detail_search a WHERE a.Applicability = 'No' order by a.BT 
desc);
```

I don't know what is happening, can anyone good in oracle help me find what I am missing.

Comment: In ANSI SQL execute immediate is only for sql statements with no input or output data. (E.g. "delete from table where x = y", or "insert into table values (1,2,3)" etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution to my problem. I should not have used INTO statement in select statement while executing with execute immediate.

I should have used like this

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement INTO RuleCount;
```

Comment: Congratulation for solving your issue yourself. Please, [self-accept your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to mark the question as answered. This will help other peoples searching for the same issue from the Internet.